# Search and replace: What's the proper shortcut?

Tags: windows, user-interface, shortcut

Very simple dilemma. A user needs to be able to do a search-and-replace in a large piece of text. Code to do this is a piece of cake. No problems there. Works like a charm! Don't break your head over that. That's solved! It's a non-issue...

No, problem is defining a good shortcut for this function. While I would prefer to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> as shortcut for this functionality (and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> for finding text) I noticed that Microsoft is using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> as shortcut! (And <kbd>F3</kbd> to find text, although <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> mostly works too.)

So, what should be the preferred shortcut for this simple function? <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd>

And second Q for additional points: Where does <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> come from? What does the H mean? At least, the R stands for Replace but the H???

*This relates to the GUI design of a Windows application. While it's a trivial matter, it's just good to be consistent with the generally accepted norm! While GUI's aren't always popular amongst programmers, keeping your GUI consistent with the norm is definitely programming-related!*

Comment: Firstly, *what* application are we talking about? Every application will have a different shortcut. The vimmers will say :%s/foo/bar/g while the more Windows/GUI people mostly use CTRL based shortcuts.

Comment: "some smart ass", jeez do you have an ask to grind or what? I was just trying to point out that there are more options than Ctrl-R and Ctrl-H. Even on Windows. And I still don't find this to be programming related.

Comment: It's not CTRL+R in MSWord because CTRL+R is Right-align. I don't know why it's CTRL+H, though...

Comment: @Brian, you have the right of your own opinion but no matter how trivial this is, it's still very programming related in my opinion. It's about keeping applications consistent with others, so users don't have to learn different shortcuts for every application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I also think that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> is the more "obvious" and "natural" choice for replace, I'd go for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> because of consistency reasons. If users are used to replace text by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> (e.g. because they use MS Word) then they'll be happy if it works in your app as well... however, if it won't work it will be a little pain because they have to change their habits.

For searching I always use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. And if you don't need <kbd>F3</kbd> for any other purpose, just use that for searching as well. You're covered for both cases then :)

Also see [this](http://joelonsoftware.com/uibook/chapters/fog0000000061.html) blog post by Joel.

Comment: It seems like Ctrl+H is used for many Microsoft apps, not only Word. I tested in Notepad and VisualStudio.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know when or who used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> first, but the reason is very simple:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> find, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> (the next key on QWERTY) for find next, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> (the next one) for replace.

The same happends with copy-paste, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> has a logical meaning, but <kbd>X</kbd> for cut and <kbd>V</kbd> for paste are the adjacent keys.

I would rather use <kbd>H</kbd> than <kbd>R</kbd> for consistency. <kbd>R</kbd> is also used to run scripts in some programs. And I have notice that most of the people don't use these shortcuts and won't try, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> but the ones who are used to them may use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> or check it.

Comment: Why are you answering a 4 year old question? ;-)

Comment: Hahaha, I came across with it and I didn't notice it was 4 years old. In fact it's my first post, I guess that's my best; )

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> is part of the formatting shortcut keys in office, it right justifies the selected text or current paragraph. As this function is probably used more than search and replace it makes sense to give it <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

The [MS UX guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511258.aspx) (not that they stick to it themselves) has a [keyboard section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545460.aspx) where they indicate that you should use the [Windows OS shortcut keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545461.aspx) to map to similar functions - so <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> it is.

Answer (score 3):

I think <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> came from WordPerfect. Or, maybe H for repHace :O) (I am serious.)

Stick with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>. Most applications use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>. Don't confuse your users. Don't force your users to remember one-off shortcut keys. Don't annoy your users. They will not remember or bother to remember or think it is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

We not simply map the action to both shortcuts so that both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> will do the same?

Alternatively, you could make it a configurable option so that the user can decide which one they want to use.

Comment: "Ctrl+R and Ctrl+H" Really confuse the user. Keep simple, no "options".

Comment: I agree with AMissico here. Two options for the same function would be too confusing...