# Html - Images won't show up (relative link)

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink, src

I worked on a Website locally and it works well. When i put it online, images won't show up.

My html file is in "folder" & images are situated in "folder/images".

When I made my website, I used this link to put images on my html code:

```
<img src="images/firstimage.png">
```

I understand the issue here is the path I used. I would like to know if there is a way to manage this without rewriting all links 1 per 1 on my html code ?

Sorry if for this noobish question this is my firsts hours of coding. Any documentation related would be appreciated.

Greetings

Comment: Can you provide a link to the website?

Answer (score 0):

Use Ctrl+R (not in every html-editor, I often use that in *IntelliJ*) to replace the marked text with the newly entered text. So you can write *"images/"* (it will marked ALL text where it occurs) to overwrite ALL marked text with following: *"folder/images/"*

For more information look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420288/search-and-replace-whats-the-proper-shortcut)